# I am trying to POST an email adress from a text field in a form, to the following page

Tags: php

I am 'in transit' between Microsoft and VBScript on the one hand, and Linux and PHP on the other so I accept that I am missing something. The form action is happening on Submit, but I am losing the value in the text field.

```
<form name="frmDetail" method = "POST" action = "e-mail.php">
<input name = "$eMail[]" required> eMail Address</><br>
and after the form I have the following PHP code
<?PHP if (!empty($_REQUEST["$email"])){?>
<?PHP $_SESSION['sendTo'] = $REQUEST['$email'];?>
<?PHP echo $SESSION['sendTo'];}?>
```

Any ideas where I should begin looking?

Comment: Using double quotes around a `$` in PHP will cause PHP to try to evaluate that string as a variable. Use single quotes or remove the `$` from both input field in html and from the `$_POST['email']`

Comment: You have typo in $REQUEST it should be $_REQUEST and in $SESSION it should be $SESSION. What warnings does your debugger show? Fixing the typo in $REQUEST (second line from bottom) should fix your problem.